# Google service account can't impersonate GSuite user

Tags: python, google-api, google-oauth, google-calendar-api

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import googleapiclient.discovery

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'GOOGLE_SECRET.json'

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

delegated_credentials = credentials.with_subject('address@example.com')

google_calendar = googleapiclient.discovery.build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=delegated_credentials)

events = google_calendar.events().list(
    calendarId='address@example.com',
    maxResults=10
).execute()
```

The result of the foregoing code is:

```
google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('unauthorized_client: Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method.', '{\n  "error" : "unauthorized_client",\n  "error_description" : "Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method."\n}')
```

`Domain-wide delegation` is on. The service account client ID is authorized with the appropriate scopes in GSuite.

The service account works for normal credentials. It only doesn't work for delegated credentials.

I've tried different APIs (scopes) and different users in our domain.

I had a colleague try to code up a sample from scratch and he got the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're problem is that your not authorising your credentials before making the call to the [Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/) but there is a couple of differences that you have that I use in my own implementation

- Use the following import statements

  ```py
  from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
  from apiclient import discovery
  ```
- Use the [`from_json_keyfile_name`](https://oauth2client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/oauth2client.service_account.html#oauth2client.service_account.ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name) method
- Authorise the credentials and pass it as a `http` argument when building the service

Try this modification to your code:

```
from apiclient import discovery
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import httplib2

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'GOOGLE_SECRET.json'

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

# Use the create_delegated() method and authorize the delegated credentials
delegated_credentials = credentials.create_delegated('address@example.com')  
delegated_http = delegated_credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
google_calendar = discovery.build('calendar', 'v3', http=delegated_http)

events = google_calendar.events().list(
    calendarId='address@example.com',
    maxResults=10
).execute()
```

I would also suggest setting `calendarId='primary'` in your API call so that you always return the primary calendar of the user who you currently have delegated credentials for.

For more information on authenticating using `ServiceAccountCredentials` see the following link: http://oauth2client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/oauth2client.service_account.html

Comment: Thanks very much. If you remember, can you link to the documentation that helped you know how to craft this authorization? None of the examples I found on Google looked like this.

Comment: Sure can, I don't think there was one particular place that I pulled the example on delegated credentials from but I'll see what I can find

Comment: While the code sample in the question works perfectly in a similar setup with DWD service-accounts (for Sheets API v4 though, not Calendar), I was looking for a different solution that gives me credentials that I can use to authorize an `httplib2.Http()`, so I can avoid `discovery.build()`'s huge memory footprint for Sheets. Finally found your answer. I had ignored `oauth2client` b/o [deprecation warning](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2client-deprecation.html), but after a second look, it applies only to Cloud APIs.