# How can I setup alerts on account change activity in GSuite?

Tags: python, automation, google-workspace, google-directory-api

So, I want to set alerting on whenever the status of a user in gsuite changes. Like if the user's status changes from `active` to `suspended` or when a user is `deleted`.

#### My Approach

I've setup notification channels on the directory api as mentioned here : https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/push.
Then as soon as you register for the channel there's an oauth link which you need to open in a browser and allow it, the usual oauth flow.

However the problem is this `channel` gets expired after almost 2 days or 2 weeks ( not sure of the exact time ) and so I've to do this again and hence it's a manual process which needs to be taken care of quite frequently.

I want to automate this or if so someone can guide me with a better approach.

I read somewhere about delegated credentials but didn't get it to working ( don't remember the exact issue with it but it wasn't working ). I've looked up this [Google service account can't impersonate GSuite user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49374112/google-service-account-cant-impersonate-gsuite-user). This doesn't apply to my case.

I do understand there should be robot accounts for this. Just the thing is I can't figure out any good documentation of this.

I am on the GSuite Basic plan and we've around 150 users.

My code is in python.

Thanks.