# Retrieving google sheet values with google sheet api on company restricted spreadsheet

Tags: python, google-api, google-sheets-api, google-api-python-client, service-accounts

I want to be able to read a spreadsheet, that has been shared with me, inside the company I work.
I have tried adapting the script from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49374112/google-service-account-cant-impersonate-gsuite-user?noredirect=1&lq=1).
This is the code I use:

```
from apiclient import discovery
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import httplib2

scope = [
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
]

SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = "gsheetread-293005-d7e75122e4c7.json"

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=scope)

# Use the create_delegated() method and authorize the delegated credentials
delegated_credentials = credentials.create_delegated('myemail@company.com')
delegated_http = delegated_credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())

google_sheet = discovery.build('spreadsheet_id', 'v3', http=delegated_http)
```

I get an error:

> oauth2client.client.HttpAccessTokenRefreshError: unauthorized_client: Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested.

Comment: 1.  are you sure the key file you are using is for a service account.  2. what libraries did you enable in Google developer console for your project, drive, sheets?    3. Has the admin of the gsuite domain set up domain wide delegation on the service account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting means you didn't add some or all of the specified scopes (`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets`,
`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`) when granting domain-wide authority to your service account. Please follow [these steps](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority):

[image]

In step 5, you have to add both `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets`,
`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` (actually, you only need to add one, if you're just accessing a spreadsheet, but you should remove the other one from your code).

#### Additional notes:

- The library you're using, `oauth2client`, [is deprecated](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2client-deprecation.html). Use [google-auth](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) instead, which doesn't rely on `httplib2`.
- You're not using a valid service name (`spreadsheet_id`). If you want to use Sheets API, the service name should be `sheets`.
- [Sheets API V3](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/v3) is deprecated and will be shut down in January 2021. Use [V4](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api) instead.
- As I mentioned before, there's no need to use the `drive` scope if you're accessing a spreadsheet. `spreadsheets` is enough.

#### Code snippet (using non-deprecated library):

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2 import service_account

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = "gsheetread-293005-d7e75122e4c7.json"

creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
delegated_credentials = creds.with_subject('myemail@company.com')
service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=delegated_credentials)
spreadsheet = service.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId="YOUR_SPREADSHEET_ID").execute()
print(spreadsheet)
```

Comment: Thank you. I realise I need to ask access from "a super administrator of the G Suite domain".